# Converting KML/XML to Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby, parsing, xml, geospatial

So, I have the boundaries of every states in the US, from the google map KML file.

This KML file is actually a XML file.

I'm converting this file to a JS file compatible with google map in order to draw polygons on my map.

Here is an excerpt from [the file with all the coordinates](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/698af53e77c56ce3439b):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
<Document>
  <Placemark>
    <name>WA</name>
    <description><![CDATA[]]></description>
    <styleUrl>#style37</styleUrl>
    <Polygon>
      <outerBoundaryIs>
        <LinearRing>
          <tessellate>1</tessellate>
          <coordinates>
            -122.402015585862,48.2252165511906 
            -122.368333031748,48.1281417374007 
            -122.216991980112,48.0074395523983 
            -122.230120864997,47.9691133009971 
            -122.302922293019,47.9502148146411 
            -122.394492319816,47.7741760704507 
            -122.414815251142,47.6641799154458 
            -122.382220450337,47.5954090424224 
            -122.392633724016,47.510242430349 
            -122.319738644767,47.3901148739843 
            -122.325376306437,47.3443234291417 
            -122.420837154063,47.3188444009071 
            <!-- etc., 243 points altogether for WA state -->
          </coordinates>
        </LinearRing>
      </outerBoundaryIs>
    </Polygon>
  </Placemark>
```

Here is my code to convert the KML file to the JS file.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'xmlsimple'

def read_xmlfile(file_name)
  file = File.open(file_name, "r")
  data = file.read
  file.close
  return data
end

target  = "states.js"

xml_data = read_xmlfile('Stateborders.xml')

data = XmlSimple.xml_in(xml_data, 'KeyToSymbol' => true)

content = "var stateBorders = {\n"
data[:document][0].each_with_index do |item, index|
  states = item[1]
  states.each_with_index do |state, index|
      name = state[:name][0]
      coord = state[:polygon][0][:outerboundaryis][0][:linearring][0][:coordinates][0].tr("\t", "").strip.gsub(/[\n]/,") ,new google.maps.LatLng(").gsub(" ) ,", "), ");
      coord = state[:polygon][0][:outerboundaryis][0][:linearring][0][:coordinates][0].tr("\t", "").strip
      coord2 = ""
      coord.split("\n").each do |ll|
        ll = ll.split(",")
        lat = ll[1].to_s.strip
        lat = lat.to_f.round(6).to_s
        lon = ll[0].to_s.strip
        lon = lon.to_f.round(6).to_s
        coord2 << "new google.maps.LatLng("+lat+", "+lon+"), "
      end
      statecoord = "'#{name}' : [#{coord2}],".gsub(", ],","],")
      content << statecoord+"\n"
  end
end
content << "};"

File.open(target, "w+") do |f|
  f.write(content)
end
```

The code itself is fast enough but i'm sure can be much simpler/cleaner. Also for the last state I have `],` instead of `]`.

Comment: I've created the [tag:geospatial] tag instead, as it has broader applicability. The combination of [tag:xml] and [tag:geospatial] should turn up some KML-related questions.

Comment: @200_success Neat. Although maybe "gis" would be an even broader tag?

Comment: @Flambino Stack Overflow has both tags, both equally popular. I think "geospatial" is clearer to those who aren't familiar with the "gis" abbreviation.

Comment: @200_success Good point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) for parsing the KML/XML. It's a more full-featured library, which makes things easier. For instance, you can get rid of all those long lines of `[:symbol][0][:another_symbol][0]...` (or maybe xmlsimple is brilliant, but, frankly, the docs are a rambling mess, so I'd steer clear)

I'd also suggest skipping the `new google.maps.LatLng(...)`. All it does is guarantee a bunch of processing the moment the JS file is loaded. Possibly a lot of errors, too, in case GMaps hasn't loaded or isn't involved - perhaps you just want the actual coordinates, not `LatLng` objects. Or perhaps you just want one state, and don't want to bother instantiating `LatLng` objects for every state in the Union. And so on - much simpler to just write out the data

I'd also skip a lot of the "manual" string construction in the output, and use a JSON library to do the heavy lifting. In fact, I'd consider simply producing a JSON file - not a JS file. As with avoiding the `new google.maps.LatLng` stuff above, the point would be to keep data and logic separate. Although the different between JSON and JS is a matter of adding `var ... =` at the start and `;` at the end, it still changes the file from a pure data format to code.

But you know your needs better than I do, so I've mimicked your code's output in my code.

I've split everything up into methods to keep things clean. It also lets you use the parsed data for something other than JS/JSON output, if need be.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'json/ext'

# Parse the file at the given path
# See #parse_kml_doc for return value
def parse_kml_file(file)
  doc = File.open(file, 'r') { |io| Nokogiri::XML.parse(io) }
  parse_kml_doc(doc)
end

# Parse the given Nokogiri doc
# Returns an array of 2-element arrays containing
# the name and coordinates of the states
def parse_kml_doc(kml_doc)
  kml_doc.css("Placemark").map do |node| # CSS-type selectors
    state  = node.css("name").first.content.strip  # get state abbreviation
    coords = node.css("coordinates").first.content # get coords string
    coords = coords.strip.each_line.map do |line|  # parse the string
      line.strip.split(/,/).map(&:to_f) # I've skipped the rounding
    end
    [ state,  coords ] # return a tuple
  end
end

# Write out a JavaScript file with the data
def write_js_file(data, file)
  json = Hash[data].to_json
  File.open(file, 'w+') do |io|
    io << "var stateBorders = "
    io << json
    io << ";"
  end
end

# Read a KML file and write a JS file
def kml_to_js(kml_file, js_file)
  data = parse_kml_file(kml_file)
  write_js_file(data, js_file)
end

# Do everything!
kml_to_js("stateborders.kml", "stateborders.js")
```

It runs about 1.25x faster than the original; nothing spectacular there, but the code really only needs to run once anyway (at least until a state secedes)

---

Update: Ok, so if you truely want `LatLng` objects, I'd suggest doing this: Include a small snippet of JS in the file, which'll do the `LatLng` instantion when the file's loaded. I.e. something like

```
var stateBorders = (function () {
   var state, i, l, json = { .. plain json data .. };
   for(state in json) {
     if(json.hasOwnProperty(state)) {
       for(i = 0, l = json[state].length ; i++) {
         json[state][i] = new google.maps.LatLng(json[state][i][0], json[state][i][1]);
       }
     }
   }
   return json;
}());
```

It will cut the file size in half, to about 280kb (if you include the `round(6)`).

Or, if you want a file with `new google.map.LatLng(...)` repeating thousands of times, you can define a simple class:

```
 LatLng = Struct.new(:lat, :lng) do
   def to_json(*a)
     "new google.maps.LatLng(#{lat.round(6)},#{lng.round(6)})"
   end
 end
```

Use it to model coordinates (changing a line in the `parse_kml_doc` method):

```
# ...
coords = coords.strip.each_line.map do |line|
  LatLng.new(*line.strip.split(/,/).map(&:to_f))
end
# ...
```

And done. Leave the rest as-is, and it'll write out a file like you want.

Comment: This is great! Thanks a lot! You're awesome! 
I'm going to keep the `new google.maps.LatLng(...)`. The main idea is to export the kml file downloadable from https://mapsengine.google.com/map/u/0/?hl=en&pli=1 (create custom maps) and to convert it to polygons on the google maps js api v3.
I'm also going to keep the rounding, it saves +-250kb on the size of my file :)

Comment: @bl0b Updated my answer

Comment: I like the idea of the JS snippet. This is smart. Thanks a lot!!! If I would chose a more complete file like this one: http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/us_states.kml where a state have multiple polygons(typically islands), I guess I would need an array with 3 dimensions right [AllStates][All polygons in state][All coordinates in polygons]. How would you do it in the code ?

Comment: @bl0b We're wandering off of the original question here, so I can't really answer. I'd just say try something, and see if it works. If it gives you trouble, put a question up on StackOverflow; if you got it working, but think it can be better, put it up for review here.

Comment: Thanks for your help! IT's is awesome, I have something, I will put it on codereview later, I have to move on with my work :)

Answer (score 4):

@Flambino has already explained the main problems in your code. I'd only add: 1) why do you use `each_with_index` if you don't actually use the indexes? 2) Ruby would have a terrible standard library if you needed 4 lines just to read the contents of a file: `contents = File.read(path)`.

That's how I'd write it:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'json'

kml = Nokogiri::XML(open("Stateborders.xml"))
coordinates_by_state = kml.css("Placemark").map do |placemark|
  state = placemark.at_css("name").text.strip
  coordinates = placemark.at_css("coordinates").text.strip.lines.map do |line|
    line.split(",").map { |coord| coord.to_f.round(6).to_s }
  end
  [state, coordinates]
end.to_h

jscode = "var stateBorders = #{coordinates_by_state.to_json};"
File.write("stateborders.js", jscode)
```

Answer (score 4):

@Flambino and @tokland have both suggested good strategies on how your task should be done.

I want to talk about your code:

**Naming conventions**
XML file is two words - name the method accordingly - `read_xml_file`

**Useful names**
Names like `coord` and `coord2` are bad because they don't convey the true role of them, and might confuse the reader - `raw_coordinates` and `formatted_coordinates` would be better.
Any two letter variable which is used for anything less trivial than running index is not advisable, and variables named `l` and `ll` are even worse, since the letter `l` might be indistinguishable from the digit `1` in some fonts, which might be very confusing...

**Don't shadow variables**
Yes, you should not use `each_with_index`, you should use `each`. But if we assume that that is the required API - don't name the inner and out arguments with the same name (`index`).
If you know you are not going to use the argument in the body of the block, ruby conventions suggest you use the special variable name `_`:

```
data[:document][0].each_with_index do |item, _|
  states = item[1]
  states.each_with_index do |state, _|
    # ... snip ...
  end
end
```

**Redundant operations**
`split` returns a list of strings. There is no point in calling `to_s` on its children.
String concatenation implicitly calls `to_s` on all non-string elements you concat, so calling `to_s` after the rounding is also redundant.
You assign `coord` twice, totally ignoring the first assignment - that line is totally redundant.

**Don't re-use variables by changing their meaning**
One side-effect of meaningless variable names is that you might be tempted to re-use them

> ```
> coord.split("\n").each do |ll|
>   ll = ll.split(",")
> ```

when `ll` is first assigned it is a string, but then you re-assign it as an array. You do the same with `lat` and `lon`. A reader who misses such a re-assignment will be confused about what you do with the variables after it.

**When you know what elements you have in an array**
When you have an array, and all you do with it is assign the first element to variable `a`, the second element to variable `b`, etc. you can use ruby's [multiple assignment](http://nathanhoad.net/ruby-multiple-assignment) instead:

```
lat, lon = ll.split(',')
```

**Ruby's `map` chaining and keeping it DRY**
To elaborate on the multiple assignment above, it is idiomatic in ruby to use `map` to transform all elements in an array:

```
lat, lon = ll.split(',').map { |number| number.to_f.round(6) }
```

This removes the code duplication you have for `lat` and `lon`.

**What `join` does better**

> ```
> statecoord = "'#{name}' : [#{coord2}],".gsub(", ],","],")
> ```

This ugly code is needed, because inside the loop you don't know when the last element is reached. Ruby already solved this problem with `join`:

```
coord2 = coord.split("\n").map do |ll|
  # ...
  "new google.maps.LatLng("+lat+", "+lon+")"
end

statecoord = "'#{name}' : [#{coord2.join(", ")}]"
```

Same is true for `content`...